# How to extract data from a smoothed plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After I smoothed the plot with the qplot() function, I need to extract the new 'smoothed' data. I can't build a data frame from the smoothed data.

The plot is smoothed, but by building the data frame I get an error message.

I smoothed the plot with this

```
qq <- qplot(x4,y4, geom='smooth', span =0.5)
```

Afterwards, I tried this to build the data frame:

```
data.frame(qq)
```

And I got the message :

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("gg", "ggplot")’ to a data.frame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot::geom_smooth` uses different underlying functions to compute smooths, either depending on the size of the data set or the specifications of the user. For a small data set, it uses `stats::loess`, so you can get that information by running `stats::loess` yourself.

As an example, here's a smoothed ggplot based on the mtcars data set:

```
library(tidyverse)

plot.data <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(span = 0.5)
print(plot.data)
```

[image]

We can obtain that smooth ourselves by using `loess` and `predict` directly, and then packing that into a data frame:

```
loess.data <- stats::loess(wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars, span = 0.5)
loess.predict <- predict(loess.data, se = T)
loess.df <- data.frame(fit = loess.predict$fit, se = loess.predict$se.fit, mpg = mtcars$mpg, wt = mtcars$wt)


> head(loess.df)
                       fit        se  mpg    wt
Mazda RX4         2.851238 0.1746388 21.0 2.620
Mazda RX4 Wag     2.851238 0.1746388 21.0 2.875
Datsun 710        2.741055 0.1986979 22.8 2.320
Hornet 4 Drive    2.781686 0.1770399 21.4 3.215
Hornet Sportabout 3.454600 0.1967633 18.7 3.440
Valiant           3.592860 0.2072037 18.1 3.460
```

Which, as we can see by plotting it, is identical to what ggplot did on its own.

```
plot.fit <- ggplot(data = loess.df, aes(x = mpg, y = fit)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = fit - se, ymax = fit + se), alpha = 0.5)
print(plot.fit)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be a more direct solution can be using `stat_smooth`

```
qq <- qplot(x4,y4, geom='smooth', span =0.5) + stat_smooth()
```